# sql hierarchial queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some tables as shown in image, I want to achieve the output as shown in the last table. Is it possible to achieve it using a sql server query with out SP's

[image: Diagram of table]

BB

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: why don't you use inner join to achieve this result

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in following given manner. I took some liberties as relationship given by you was not very clear :

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('role') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE role
GO

CREATE TABLE role
    (
    roid   INT NULL,
    roname VARCHAR (20) NULL
    )
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('rolechild') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE rolechild
GO

CREATE TABLE rolechild
    (
    parentroid INT NULL,
    childroid  INT NULL
    )
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('rolechildrel') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE rolechildrel
GO

CREATE TABLE rolechildrel
    (
    roid   INT NULL,
    rtroid INT NULL
    )
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('rt') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE rt
GO

CREATE TABLE rt
    (
    rtid   INT NULL,
    rtname VARCHAR (20) NULL
    )
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('urore') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE urore
GO

CREATE TABLE urore
    (
    uid  INT NULL,
    roid INT NULL
    )
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('usern') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE usern
GO

CREATE TABLE usern
    (
    uid   INT NULL,
    uname VARCHAR (20) NULL
    )
GO


SELECT u.uname,r.roname,rt.rtname
FROM
usern u JOIN urore ur ON (u.uid = ur.uid)
JOIN role r ON (ur.roid = r.roid)
JOIN rolechild rc ON (r.roid = rc.parentroid)
JOIN rolechildrel rcl ON (rc.childroid = rcl.roid)
JOIN rt ON rcl.rtroid = rt.rtid
```